# CSS - Padding on a background image

Tags: html, css, transparency

The following code ususally works well for me when I am using .gif or jpg images..

```css
#contentBox1{ position:relative; width:980px; background:url(../images/bg-middle.png) repeat-y; min-height:80px;   }
#contentBox2{ position:relative; width:980px; background:url(../images/bg-top.png) no-repeat top; }
#contentBox3{ position:relative; width:980px; background:url(../images/bg-bottom.png) no-repeat bottom; min-height:500px; }

<div id="contentBox1"> <div id="contentBox2"> <div id="contentBox3">  Content Text Goes Here. </div> </div> </div>
```

But as you can see I use .png because everything needs transparency to see through to the background. So the "middle.png" background shows up behind the header and footer. I need all the room I can in this div at the top and bottom but can't seem how to figure out the best css code to make this work.

[Example](http://webdesignmb.com/test/)

Comment: unable to understand your question. please explain further.

Comment: Have you considered specifying the position of the background image?

Comment: Like left or right? They are specified top and bottom

Comment: I thought maybe there was a way to give a background "padding" but that seems to work only from the left not the top or bottom...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

1. Combine the `top + middle` **images** into one image and make the middle section really long.
2. Place that as the `background image` of a div.
3. Inside the above div place a second `div` with the bottom image aligned to the bottom of this div as a background image. Make the bottom image not transparent but have it filled around the cloud by the yellow `bg colour`.

Comment: Okay I see how this works..but its kind of a work around isn't it? being that they are.png24 it will be larger file size to do this. I was hoping there was a slimmer way! Thanks

Comment: The other problem will be if i remove transparency from around the bottom part of the cloud, it will cover any background image I have...

Answer (score 0):

try this, re-order your div's as follows

```
<body>
<div id="contentBox2"></div>
<div id="contentBox1">
      <div id="content">Content Goes Here</div>
</div>
<div id="contentBox3"></div>
</body>
```

Then change the CSS as follows, this is a more logical layout and should be easier to follow, the internal #content div will add padding to the text so it appears inside the image. The min-height of the top and bottom divs are set to the height of the images so you don't have any background color seeping through. You can change the min-height of #ContentBox1 to your desired size.

```css
#contentBox2 {
    background: url("images/bg-top.png") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 304px;
    position: relative;
    width: 980px;
}

#contentBox1 {
    background: url("images/bg-middle.png") repeat-y scroll 0 0 transparent;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 560px;
    position: relative;
    width: 980px;
}

#contentBox3 {
    background: url("images/bg-bottom.png") no-repeat scroll center bottom transparent;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 240px;
    position: relative;
    width: 980px;
}

#content {
    padding: 40px;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with this method is that it is not 100% correct. I'm not sure if i can explain this right, but hen you stack divs vertically, it will not always be flush on all browsers, it is not natural (unlike floating left and right it will always be flush).

Comment: But this is yet another way, the work around would be to add a -15 or so(seems to vary by browser) top margin to content1 and content3 which would cover any gaps that might occur. Still seems like there is a better way.

Comment: It should be flush on all browsers as using the margin:0 auto; will set the left and right margins to be the same, so any issue then is down to the images.

Comment: I suppose that could also work. But there is still going to be a large gap because the height of the top image, and I want that space

Answer (score 0):

I used a little bit of Billys suggestiong but changed it up a bit. The restrictions are it has a max-height.

```css
#contentBox1{ position:relative; width:980px; background:url(images/bg-top.png) repeat-y top left; min-height:300px;  margin:0 auto;   }
#contentBox3{ position:absolute; bottom:-218px; width:980px; height:218px;  background:url(images/bg-bottom.png) no-repeat left bottom;  }  /* bg image is 240px; */
#content{ width:900px; position:relative; margin:0 auto; padding-top:85px;}

<div id="contentBox1">   <div id="content">Content text goes here. </div> <div id="contentBox3">  </div> </div>
```

You can see http://webdesignmb.com/test/

Comment: Problem now is that if you're page has a large amount of text or images in your content div, your design will break and the top image reappears half way down the document with the background visible through the text. I've broken it using Firebug with about 20 lines of text!